# Single Instance per Machine of a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a taskbar application that I want to ensure that one and only one instance is running. In an article called, [*WPF Single Instance Best Practices*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20871/wpf-single-instance-best-practices), Evan Wondrasek posted a great answer and I have added it to my application. This appears to work really well with one small exception.

When I implemented this I have lost my splash screen and I do not know why. Can anyone explain why my splash screen no longer works and how I might get the splash screen working again? I used a simple PNG file and marked its properties as a SplashScreen. I am beginning to think I may need to do something with the SplashScreen class to fix this.

TIA, Doug

Answer (score 0):

By implementing the answer in the link you supplied, you replaced the Main function & startup object of your application. You will need to create the SplashScreen object yourself now, put this inside your own Main method:

```
SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen("images/logo.png");
splashScreen.Show(true);
```

See this link for more information: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33894287-101a-4c9f-8c6a-f0452ab4ced0/splash-screen-not-displaying-anymore-on-startup?forum=wpf

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was something like this. Splashscreen is back.

I would vote but I guess my reputation is not good enough!